# Clarification on using regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have an expression as below:

```
abc_d_efg =  'Faulty' || test1= 'NotUsed' || sample_true = 'Empty'
```

I want to filter out all the left hand side labels. That is the Final list should be like:

```
list = ['abc_d_efg','test1','sample_true']
```

I have tried:

```
re.findall("\w*_\w*_\w*",string_CAN)
```

But this returns only `abc_d_efg`

```
Signals = []
String = "abc_d_efg =  'Faulty' || test1= 'NotUsed' || sample_true = 
'Empty' "
Signals = re.findall("\w*_\w*_\w*",string_CAN)
print(Signals)
```

Actual Output: `['abc_d_efg']`
Expected Output: `['abc_d_efg','test1','sample_true']`

Comment: sorry, the third line of code is :  Signals = re.findall("\w*_\w*_\w*",String)

Comment: You can always edit your question if you need add something.

Comment: You can try this: `(?:([^=]+)(?==)[^|]*\|\|)+(?:([^=]+)(?==).*)`, but it'll only capture the last two labels...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your expression searches for strings with three underscores, you should try looking for something trailed by an = . You can use a positive look ahead:

Try:

```
\w* ?(?=\=)
```

PS: https://regexr.com might help

Comment: The same way how can i split that comes after the '=' symbol?

Comment: You will have to use a lookbehind: (?<=\=) NOTE: A lookbehind isn't supported in all interpreters . A way to find everything in your string would be: (?<=\=)[ \t\r\n]*\'\w*\' . NOTE: The line breaks might be superfluous, but there is a line break in the string you have given.

Comment: 'a !=5
b >=1
c ==1
d <= 2
e <2' . From this string, i want to get a list of all the labels that are before the comparison operator and another list that contains the values after the comparison operator. that is list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e'] and list2 = ['5','1','1','2','2']. How will i be able to do that?

Comment: The direction you are going is parsing which is what @ForceBru describes in his answer. *Programming languages are not regular* However in the particular case you are describing, regex still works fine: All your variables are strings of alfa chars: [a-zA-Z]+ and all your values are digits: \d+

Answer (score 1):

Looks like regexes are too weak to handle this because they only give you access to the last value of a repeated capture group, but we need all of these values. But fear not, it's overkill time!

Here's a recursive descent parser that will validate the string and return the list of labels from it.

It uses the following grammar (in BNF; terminals in uppercase; the starting symbol is `expression`):

```
expression:
    assignment | (assignment OR expression)
assignment:
    NAME ASSIGN STRING
```

Code:

```
import re

class Token:
    def __init__(self, type: str, string: str, span: tuple):
        self.type, self.string, self.span = type, string, span

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Token({self.type}, {self.string!r}, {self.span})'


def lex(data: str) -> list:
    '''
    Tokenize the string `data` and yield non-SPACE tokens.
    Valid token types (see `(?P<TOKEN_TYPE>...)` in the regex below):
        ASSIGN, NAME, OR, SPACE, STRING
    '''
    regex = re.compile(r"(?P<NAME>[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|(?P<STRING>'[^']*')|(?P<ASSIGN>\=)|(?P<OR>\|\|)|(?P<SPACE>\s+)")
    retval = []
    i, maxlen = 0, len(data)
    while i < maxlen:
        match = regex.match(data[i:])
        if not match:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid token at index {i}')

        begin, end = match.span()
        begin += i
        end += i
        i += match.end()

        token = Token(match.lastgroup, match.group(), (begin, end))

        if token.type != 'SPACE':
            yield token

class Parser:
    '''
    Grammar is the following.

    expression:
        assignment | (assignment OR expression)
    assignment:
        NAME ASSIGN STRING
    '''
    def __init__(self, code: str):
        self.code = code
        self.last_valid_token_end = 0
        self.tokens = lex(code)

    def next_token(self, expected_types: set, recursion_depth: int) -> Token:
        '''
        Return the next token. If the `self.tokens` iterable is empty, return the special EMPTY token.
        Raise an exception if the token's type is not in `expected_types`.
        '''

        try:
            token = next(self.tokens)
        except StopIteration:
            token = Token('EMPTY', '', (self.last_valid_token_end, self.last_valid_token_end + 1))
        else:
            _, self.last_valid_token_end = token.span

        if token.type not in expected_types:
            line_thing = self.code[
                (token.span[0] - 4) if token.span[0] >= 4 else 0:token.span[1] + 4
            ]
            raise ValueError(
                f'Unexpected token {token}, expected one of {expected_types} '
                f'at line {line_thing!r}'
            )

        print('\t' * recursion_depth + token.type)

        return token

    def parse(self):
        '''
        Start parsing from recursion level zero. Recursion levels are needed to pretty-print
        the syntax tree for debugging only.
        '''
        return self.expression(0)

    def expression(self, i: int):
        '''
        Parse the `expression` production from the grammar.
        Return a list of wharever is returned by `self.assignment`.
        '''

        print('\t' * i + 'expression')

        assignments = [self.assignment(i + 1)]  # parse the `assignment` production

        next_token = self.next_token({'OR', 'EMPTY'}, i + 1)  # the next token must be either OR or EMPTY
        if next_token.type == 'OR':
            assignments.extend(self.expression(i + 1))  # parse the `expression` production
            next_token = self.next_token({'EMPTY'}, i + 1)  # the next token must be EMPTY

        return assignments   

    def assignment(self, i: int):
        '''
        Parse the `assignment` production from the grammar.
        Return the string that corresponds to the NAME token in the grammar.
        '''
        print('\t' * i + 'assignment')

        name, assign, string = (
            self.next_token({'NAME'}  , i + 1),
            self.next_token({'ASSIGN'}, i + 1),
            self.next_token({'STRING'}, i + 1)
        )

        return name.string


CODE = "abc_d_efg =  'Faulty' || test1= 'NotUsed' || sample_true = 'Empty'"
result = Parser(CODE).parse()
print(result)
```

Output:

```
expression
    assignment
        NAME
        ASSIGN
        STRING
    OR
    expression
        assignment
            NAME
            ASSIGN
            STRING
        OR
        expression
            assignment
                NAME
                ASSIGN
                STRING
            EMPTY
        EMPTY
    EMPTY
['abc_d_efg', 'test1', 'sample_true']
```

Remove all `print` statements from the `Parser` class to disable debug output, that is, everything above `['abc_d_efg', 'test1', 'sample_true']`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using list comprehension with `re.findall()`

```
import re
your_string = "abc_d_efg =  'Faulty' || test1 = 'NotUsed' || sample_true = 'Empty'"
your_labels = [v.strip() for v in re.findall("\w* ? (?=\=)", your_string)]
print(your_labels)

# Gives expected output
['abc_d_efg', 'test1', 'sample_true']
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are (incorrectly) borrowing my regex, you might also upvote my answer. Seems like the polite thing to do. Also: This regex is not going to produce that output (it'll miss test1)

Comment: Nein! Yours is looking for a word followed by compulsory space then an optional space, followed by a non capturing = . Since the second match has no space between the word and the =, hence this expression will not capture it. Try it yourself: https://regexr.com/